# how to calculate the total price of a shopping cart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to calculate the total price of my card, according to the following formula price unit * qty unit of each line and at the end have the total of the card

this is my Model

```
export class CdmdetailModel{
idref!:string;
designation!:string;
qte!:number;
price!:number;
reduction!:number;
puht!:number
 }
```

in my car, I have a list of products

```
detailItem: CdmdetailModel[] = [];
```

**here a i add item in my detailItem card**

```
addToCart() {
let lcom = new  
CdmdetailModel(this.refech,this.designation,this.qteech,this.priceech,this.reductionech)
this.detailItem.push(lcom)
this.toastrService.showSuccess('Ajouté au commande')
this.addbtn=false 
this.clear()  
this.totalQuantity = this.detailItem.length
this.clculPritotal1()
}
```

I created two methods to try to obtain the total value of the card with this method,

1.Method

```
clculPritotal(){
  for (let index = 0; index < this.detailItem.length; index++) {
   this.totalPriceCalcul.push(this.detailItem[index].price * this.detailItem[index].qte )
  }
  const  reducer = (accumulator:any,currentValue:any)=>accumulator+currentValue;
   this.totprice = this.totalPriceCalcul.reduce(reducer,0)
   console.log('Tot method 1', this.totprice )
}
```

2.mtehod

```
clculPritotal1(){
  this.detailItem.map((lc)=>{
    this.totprice += lc.price*lc.qte
    console.log('Tot method 2', this.totprice )
  })
}
```

[image]

can someone help me?

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Also, this doesn't look like [tag:angularjs] so I removed those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to keep your utility functions simple, task-oriented, and separate from your UI. Pass in whatever values your function needs to perform a calculation, and let the function return a result.

In this case, you could return an object that summarizes line count, piece count and total.

```
function cartSummary(items) {
    let summary={lineCount:0, pieceCount:0, totalAmt:0.0};
    items.forEach(item => {
        summary.lineCount++;
        summary.pieceCount += item.qte;
        summary.totalAmt += item.qte * item.price;
    });
    return summary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a widespread use case.
Use array.prototype.reduce()

for instance:

```
const items = [
  {
    productName: "apple",
    price: 10,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    productName: "banana",
    price: 20,
    quantity: 3
  }
]

const total = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + item.price * item.quantity
}, 0)

console.log(total) // 80
```